# Convert unformatted to formatted .dat file

Tags: fortran, file-conversion, formatted

I have a .dat file in an unformatted format and I would like to convert it to a formatted format as I cannot visualize the values and use them easily in Matlab.

The file is created with this code:

```
do i=1,nxyz 
   tzmt(i,1,1)=tzmt(i,1,1)+tz(i,1,1)
enddo

if (mod(itime,isave).eq.0) then
   open(75,file='vmt.dat',form='unformatted')
   write(75) tzmt
   close(75)enter code here
endif
```

Do you have an idea of what I could do it (I am a beginner in Fortran)?

Comment: Are you able to read that file using a second Fortran program, or do you no longer have access to a system which matches that used to write the file?

Comment: Be aware that Fortran 90 is just one very old, even if groundbraking, version of the Fortran standard. The .f90 file extension just says it is the modern free source form, it can be any later standard revision.